# How to join two or more columns from one table with one column from another table, even there are NULL values in first table columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have multiple columns (some of them have NULL value) on one table and I have to join them in another table's column.

When I try to merge them with:

```
WHERE users.job_one = jobs.id_job
AND users.job_two = jobs.id_job
```

SQL:

```
SELECT users.id,users.name,users.job_one,users.job_two,jobs.*
FROM users,jobs 
WHERE users.job_one = jobs.id_job
AND users.job_two = jobs.id_job
```

I expect to display a person with one job or two, but I get an empty result.

Comment: Hint: If you want to display users with job one `OR` two, you probably want to use `OR` and not `AND`.

Comment: How do you want `NULL` values handled?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match `NULL` values, use the `NULL` safe comparison operator `<=>`:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, u.job_one, u.job_two, j.*
FROM users u JOIN
     jobs j
     ON u.job_one <=> jobs.id_job AND
        u.job_two <=> j.id_job;
```